Errors when installing WINE
I am using Ubuntu 24.04. Since I did not see Wine in the software from Ubuntu, I went online to see how to install via the command line. I did install it. However, when I do a general sudo-apt-get update I get these errors. Note: I have went and installed the Wine via the snapcraft app, and then re-installed it using the Snapcraft app. However, i still get this same error: (how to I get rid of this). Also, I had installed the Play on Linux app, but it would never actually open the app but would quickly revert to my web browser. sigh.
F:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease [6,259 B]
Get:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease [6,261 B]       
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                      
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Err:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]     
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Err:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
arlene@arlene-ASUS-TUF-Gaming-A15-FA506NF-FA506NF:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                      
Get:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease [6,259 B]      
Get:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease [6,261 B]       
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease   
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Err:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Err:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


Which method did you use specifically? There is a good complete guide here:
https://wine.htmlvalidator.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-24.04.html

Take a look at this line:Get:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy. You should remove or disable this repository from your sources, it's for groovy, not for noble.

Undo all that you have done and install the version from the Ubuntu repos. 24.04 has version 9.0 of wine included in its repos. https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/wine
